# embed telegram chat client in website

Tags: telegram

I thought of only 1 option but not sure how to implement it as well: to create and embed Microsoft Bot Framework Web Chat Client and use it to send/receive messages between my website and telegram. appreciate any guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want us to help, please provide us some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we have more info to help you

Comment: hello @DamCx, i am looking for advice to embed a telegram chat in a website as i do not know how best to implement this yet.

Comment: What have you tried, for far?

Comment: today you can do it with getUpdates()

Answer (score 11):

Free live chat widget linked to your Telegram messenger can be added to any website using Intergram.

See this open-source project on GitHub -
https://github.com/idoco/intergram

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you want something like [Telegram Web](http://web.telegram.org/) in your website, I think the best idea is to take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram).

Here are some obstacles on your way:

1. Making a complete telegram client is very complex.
2. Every user must authenticate within your client. Which means an SMS will be sent to them and they have to confirm the code.
3. You should hire a team to keep it updated! Telegram adds new features almost every week.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty complex solution :) a simpler approach would be so setup a proxy/bot to tunnel the messages to Telegram